# Why sum(args) is okay to run but sum(*args) is not okay

Tags: python

```
def super_func(*args, **kwargs):
  return sum(*args)

print(super_func(1,2))
```

When I run this code, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(super_func(1,2))
  File "main.py", line 2, in super_func
    return sum(*args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I can simply fix the error by using `return sum(args)` instead of `return sum(*args)`, but why should I remove the `*` in the beginning of `args`?

Comment: What would you expect from `sum(1, 2)`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 1):

Because [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) accepts one positional argument. `sum(args)` is equivalent to `sum([1, 2])` (except with the tuple instead of a list, but it's easier to see that way), while `sum(*args)` is equivalent to `sum(1, 2)`.